# How to integrate map and filter with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The demo code in pure python is:

```py
arr = [...]
new_arr = []

for x in arr:
    y = f(x)
    if y > 0:
        new_arr.append(y)

return new_arr
```

How to transform it to pandas methods in same style, which says first map and then filter meanwhile? If it is not the same time, it may raise default dtype error.

Answer (score 1):

You can call function per values of column `col`, then compare ouput and set new column in [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = df['col'].apply(f)
mask = s > 0

df['new'] = np.where(mask, s, np.nan)
```